# ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem in loop | Splitting to Child threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, threadpool

I have one main Thread which collects the active jobs from my database to process.
I want to split this jobs to multithread without any crashes or high CPU issue.

So I've selected the way to use ThreadPool. My Main Thread calls by another thread and works as following:

```
    private void startChipDataManagment()
    {
        fillQueu();
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(_threadCount, _threadCount);
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(_threadCount, _threadCount);
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MainJobsQueuList.Count; i++)
            {
                job CurrentJob = MainJobsQueuList[i];
                if (isSystemAlive())
                {
                    JobDataGenerationThread singleJobThread = new JobDataGenerationThread(CurrentJob.id, this);
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(singleJobThread.processJob), singleJobThread);
                    Thread.Sleep(0);
                }
            }

            while (_jobQueueCount > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            if (MainJobsQueuList.Count > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                MainJobsQueuList.Clear();
                _jobQueueCount = 0;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(FILE_PROCESSED_AFTER_WAIT_TIME);
            fillQueu();
            
        } while (true);
     }

    private object syncLock = new object();
    public object syncLockChild = new object();
    int _jobQueueCount = 0;

    public void increaseThreadCount()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            _jobQueueCount++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count increased. Current Count : {0}", _jobQueueCount);
    }
    public void decreaseThreadCount()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            _jobQueueCount--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count decreased. Current Count : {0}", _jobQueueCount);
    }
```

My SingleJobThread Class as following:

```
    public JobDataGenerationThread(long assignedJobId, DataGenerationManagerThreadPoolNew mainThreadPool)
    {
        dbContextThread = new emvEntities();
        //currentJob = assignedJob;
        currentJobId = assignedJobId;
        CurrentAppSettings = new Settings();
        CurrentAppSettings.ReadSettings();

        SettingsManager SM = new SettingsManager();
        Deskey = SM.GetDesKey();

        _mainThreadPool = mainThreadPool;
    }

    public void processJob(object obj)
    {
        TimeSpan stTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        job SingleJob = /*currentJob;*/ GetSelectedJob(currentJobId);
        try
        {                
            _mainThreadPool.increaseThreadCount();
            /*Do some work.. Change flags of some Jobs*/
        }
        catch (Exception ext) {
            LogGenerator.WriteLog(NLog.LogLevel.Error, 1, LogGenerator.ModuleType.DataEngine, "I see Error : " + ext.ToString() + "MY JOB ID :" + currentJobId, true);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                SingleJob.isDataProcessingStarted = true;
                SingleJob.creationdate = DateTime.Now;
                dbContextThread.SaveChanges();
                _mainThreadPool.decreaseThreadCount();
                TimeSpan etTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                LogGenerator.WriteLog(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, 1, LogGenerator.ModuleType.DataEngine, string.Format("I have Taken total: {0} seconds. My JOB ID is : {1}", etTime - stTime, currentJobId), true);
                //Console.WriteLine("I have taken total : {0} seconds", etTime - stTime);
            }
            catch (Exception excpt)
            {
                LogGenerator.WriteLog(NLog.LogLevel.Error, 1, LogGenerator.ModuleType.DataEngine, string.Format("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!FATAL ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! \r\n{0}", excpt.ToString()), true, excpt);
                Console.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!FATAL ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! {0}\r\n", excpt.ToString());
            }
        }
```

However I implemet this logic, I don't believe the ThreadCount which I set is correctly set for the ThreadPool and I also have some concerns like creating the JobDataGenerationThread object in loop and calling it's function in ThreadPool is fine? My project performance not increased as aspected. What I am missing?

I will be appreciated for any Input.. Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks to David-Browne answer I updated my code like the following and removed garbage codes. So this seems more thread safe than my previous code.

```
            Parallel.ForEach(MainJobsQueuList, opt, job =>
            {
                if (isSystemAlive())
                {
                    JobDataGenerationThread singleJobThread = new JobDataGenerationThread(job.id, this);
                    singleJobThread.processJob();
                }
            });
```

I removed the processJob functions that gets object.
However all the efforts that I spent, I see that performance problem was because of another application which I call had some limits for supporting multithread process..

Comment: How about just a [parallel for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: Hello @Wyck can you give more explanation please? Where you want me to think on about a parallel for loop?

Comment: Setting the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` is a recipe for disaster, especially with a low value. Your program may crash with an uncatchable exception at any random moment. Why do such a thing?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I would like to set the thread count according to Server features. So I search and saw that people are setting the Thread count for pool like this. If there is any better input please suggest me

Comment: If you have a hard requirement to never use more than X `ThreadPool` threads, and fulfilling this requirement is more important than your application continue running, then by all means do use the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` method. It sounds like a strange requirement to me, but you may have your reasons, and these reasons could be valid.

Comment: I'd liked to set exact thread counts in threadpool and recognized that you can't set it until you set min and max thread counts. So that's why I've used the ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads line. Yes also I have some reasons to not run Application with huge count of thread

Answer (score 2):

Parallel loop would simply be something like:

```
var opt = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };
Parallel.ForEach(MainJobsQueuList, opt, job => ProcessJob(job));
```

to replace virtually all that code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But in fact my Main Thread calls the fillQueue function in parallel. It means I don't wait for the singleJob to be processed in my for loop. It just splits the jobs to threads. Also I need to define the object "JobDataGenerationThread" to pass some variables in it.
You think this one can be suitable for my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a BlockingCollection rather than a List.  Then you can the readers will block while you add items.

Comment: I am already blocking to adding on list with some conditions like in my code in above so noone will add there until unless the process done